# Polynomial with alternating sign coefficients from the odd degree terms of a Truncated Power Series

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, series-expansion

I'm trying to make a function that will take any truncated power series I give it, strip away all the even degree terms, then change the sign of the coefficients of every other term. So that we have a polynomial with only odd degree terms with alternating sign.

```
f = 2^x;
ff = Normal[Series[f, {x, 0, 10}]];
ffOdd = FromCoefficientRules[
    Pick[
        CoefficientRules[ff, x],
        And @@ OddQ[#[[1]]] & /@ CoefficientRules[ff, x]],
    x]
```

I've been able to figure out everything but the alternating sign part.

**Update:**

Expanding on DumpsterDoofus's answer I was able to mix and match the desired properties as well:

```
n = 10;
f[x_] := 2^x;
fSeries = Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, n}]]
fOdd = Normal[Series[(f[x] - f[-x])/2, {x, 0, n}]]
fEven = Normal[Series[(f[x] + f[-x])/2, {x, 0, n}]]
fOddAlt = Normal[Series[(f[I x] - f[-I x])/(2 I), {x, 0, n}]]
fEvenAlt = Normal[Series[(f[I x] + f[-I x])/2, {x, 0, n}]]
```

Comment: Just to point out a small thing: If we change the sign of every other odd power term, we do not always get a polynomial with only odd degree terms with alternating sign.  For example, `f = Sin[x]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is to note that for any function $f$ with a convergent power series, the quasi-hyperbolic function $$g(x)=\frac{f(ix)-f(-ix)}{2i}$$ has the power series of $f$ with only odd, alternating sign terms (provided that it converges).

Here's an example:

```
f[x_] := x + x^2 + x^3 - x^4;
(f[I x] - f[-I x])/(2 I) // Simplify
```

which produces

```
x - x^3
```

Comment: very nice +1 :)

Comment: Hey! That's cheating! You know maths!

Comment: @belisarius: Huge thanks to [Spot and Blasternaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Blaster_Episode_I:_In_Search_of_Spot).

Comment: @BobHanlon: Yup, you're right, it looks like it fails when $f$ doesn't have a convergent series (and I imagine there's cases where it fails even when it does), edited answer to address this. It does seem to work with $f(x)=\log(1+x)$ though, presumably because it has a convergent series.

Comment: Convergence seems a side issue since in the question we're given a Taylor polynomial to operate on..  (+1)

Comment: Is "quasi-hyperbolic function" standard terminology? I'm having difficulty researching it further through Google, even after filtering out the economics results.

Comment: I think `Expand` might be more appropriate than `Simplify` here. +1 of course.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 9;
l = CoefficientList[Series[E^x, {x, 0, n}], x];
l1 = PadRight[#, Length@l, #] &@ {0, 1, 0, -1};
Expand@FromDigits[Reverse[l l1] , x]

(* x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880 *)
```

Or using `CoefficientRules[]`:

```
FromCoefficientRules[
 CoefficientRules[
       Normal@Series[E^x , {x, 0, n}], x] /. ({n_} -> x_) /; EvenQ@n        :> {n} -> 0 
                                          /. ({n_} -> x_) /; Mod[n, 4] != 1 :> {n} -> -x, x]
```

Or even:

```
Expand@FromDigits[Table[SeriesCoefficient[Exp[x], {x, 0, m}] Mod[(2 + m) (4 + m (4 + 3 m)), 4, -1], 
                                         {m, n, 0, -1}], x]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func[pol_, var_] := 
 FromCoefficientRules[
  MapIndexed[First@#1 -> Last@#1 (-1)^(First@#2 - 1) &, 
   SortBy[Cases[List @@@ CoefficientRules[Normal@pol], {{_?OddQ}, _}],
     First]], var]
```

e.g. `func[ff,t]`

yields:

```
t Log[2] - 1/6 t^3 Log[2]^3 + 1/120 t^5 Log[2]^5 - (
 t^7 Log[2]^7)/5040 + (t^9 Log[2]^9)/362880
```

and

```
func[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 10}], t]
```

yields:

```
t - t^3/6 + t^5/120 - t^7/5040 + t^9/362880
```